# Notify about upstream git repo changes?

Tags: magit, git

I have a repo for my dotfiles and update it here and there on various computers. Sometimes I forget to `git pull` before editting and `git push`. This creates conflicts or trigger `git merge`, or I just forget that I wrote a new feature somewhere else already. So, how do I do the following:

1. check every `n` minutes for remote repo changes and give a message
   to the current frame so I can pull the changes before doing something
   else.
2. When opening (`find-file`) on the repo, do the same check changes and notification.
3. (expansion for other use cases) if I am not working on the repo, but I still want to get notitfy about changes on a list of repos something like this:

   `((repo1 "git@host:/path/to/repo1")
   (repo2 "git@github.com:user/repo2"))`

   if there are changes on `repo1` then I will get a notification saying `"There are changes on repo1. Check it out!"`

Comment: there is the `magit-status-refresh-hook` that you can attach a pull to

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against setting up some mechanism to automatically pull. Personally I avoid even pulling manually. What I usually do instead is to first only fetch. Once I have done that I can see what new commits, if any, were "created elsewhere". I can then inspect those changes and decide, on a case by case basis, whether it is appropriate to merge or to rebase.

Usually I rebase, which can be done using <kbd>r</kbd>, followed by <kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>e <branch> RET</kbd> as appropriate.

If after doing it explicitly like this for a while, you find that you always rebase (and I would assume that for dotfile repositories this might actually be the case), you can also configure pull to always rebase. To do so type <kbd>b</kbd> to bring up the branch configuration popup and then type <kbd>M-r</kbd> until `true` is highlighted on the `pull.rebase` line (i.e. set the repository-local value of `pull.rebase` to `true`). Alternatively you can configure just the current branch to be always rebase, using the same popup.

Comment: I can partially agree with not automatic pull, but still want to do get automatic notification. I think I have some clues, I will implement it and come back later